# Why when both audio and video MediaStreamTracks enabled parameter set to false, "on-air" indicator keeps being turned on?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, w3c, getusermedia

W3C http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#life-cycle-and-media-flow article on media flow lifecycle says:

> When all tracks connected to a source are muted or disabled, the "on-air" or "recording" indicator for that source can be turned off; when the track is no longer muted or disabled, it must be turned back on.

Is mentioned behaviour implemented in Chrome or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Update:** Firefox now supports [turning off the camera light on mute](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/better-privacy-on-camera-mute-in-firefox-60/).* Edits in ***bold***.

I gather from the subject that you know the answer is no.

Neither Chrome nor Firefox turn off the camera light while a site (temporarily) disables a camera stream. The spec says "can" for turning it off, but "MUST" for turning it back on, so both browsers are in compliance.

You can try it here:

```js
var start = () => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
  .then(stream => video.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(e => log(e.name));

toggle.onclick = () => {
  var track = video.srcObject && video.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0];
  if (!track) return;
  toggle.innerHTML = (track.enabled = !track.enabled) ? "Disable" : "Enable";
}

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
```

```html
<video id="video" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video><br>
<button onclick="start()">Start!</button>
<button id="toggle">Disable</button><div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

**Note:** In Chrome use https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/b6tyjm4s/ instead (getUserMedia + snippets != <3).

As to why, the [spec also says](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#implementation-suggestions):

> When permission is not stored, permission should last only until such time as all MediaStreamTracks sourced from that device have been stopped.

This is observable from the camera light ***as well as in-browser camera & microphone live indicators***. For non-persistent permissions, both browsers guarantee users that a site's access ends when the camera light goes off. *Turning off the light while a site temporarily disables a stream would break this guarantee. **In-browser indicators may buttress this problem.***

I'd have to speculate when it comes to `https` in Chrome, but at least for Firefox, where permission grants are non-persistent by default, this is why.

Comment: Thank you! Keeping camera light turned on really makes sense.