# Webrtc disable track doesn't turn off webcam

Tags: webrtc, mediastream

I am trying to implement a toggle video feature using webRTC. Refer to the following code:

```
<video id="remote" autoPlay></video>
<button onclick="toggleVideo()">Toggle video</button>
```

```
let localVideo = document.querySelector('#local');

const toggleVideo = () => {
    localVideo.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = !localVideo.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled
}
```

This turns off video as well as webcam indicator in firefox but not in chrome. Chrome only turns off the video.

According to MDN docs,

> If the MediaStreamTrack represents the video input from a camera, **disabling the track by setting enabled to false also updates device activity indicators to show that the camera is not currently recording or streaming**. For example, the green "in use" light next to the camera in iMac and MacBook computers turns off while the track is muted in this way.

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/enabled)
Is there any other workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why when both audio and video MediaStreamTracks enabled parameter set to false, "on-air" indicator keeps being turned on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304281/why-when-both-audio-and-video-mediastreamtracks-enabled-parameter-set-to-false)

Comment: No, I have seen many applications which have this feature. The mentioned question doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: So the light does not stop blinking for you on chrome, if you stop the track? `localVideo.srcObject.getVideoTracks()[0].stop()`

Comment: Yes, you are correct.